# How to align these buttons?

Tags: html, css

I have this site.

http://test2.dac-proiect.ro/wp/

I want to align these buttons.

http://i61.tinypic.com/68u44i.jpg

I inspected with Firebug source code and we did not discover where the problem comes.
It is a site made with Wordpress.

Can you help me with any ideas please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Move `.btn-add` out of its container (to same level with `.quick-view`) and add `display:inline-block` to both...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in the same div box:

```
<div class="button-groups add-button clearfix">

   <div class="wb-posted_in">Brands: <a href="http://test2.dac-proiect.ro/wp/?product_brand=nike" rel="tag">Nike</a></div> 

        <div class="btn-cart">
             <a class="add_to_cart_button product_type_simple" data-quantity="1" data-product_sku="" data-product_id="116" rel="nofollow" href="/wp/?add-to-cart=116"><i class="icon-cart fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><span class="title-cart">Add to cart</span></a>
        </div> 

        <div class="quick-view">
             <a data-target="#wpo_modal_quickview" data-toggle="modal" data-productslug="cream-colored-venenatis-faucib" class="quickview btn-action btn-outline-inverse" href="#"> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"> Quick View</span><span class="hidden-lg"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"> </i></span></a> 
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Then display them inline:

```
.btn-cart {
   display: inline;
}

.quick-view {
    display: inline;
}
```

- Edited to `display: inline;` for a cleaner solution thanks to poncha's comment.

Result:
[image: Result]

Comment: Now you got +1 ;) But I'd say the result is not perfect ;) (the buttons are not aligned in the middle of the container). If you'd use `display` instead of `float`, it would be easier

Comment: I didn't think of that. Updated my answer with your suggestion. Much better.

Answer (score 0):

You can put both in another parent element to hold them in (I personally like to use `<span>` ), once in the div, change both buttons float, so the first button with be `float:left;` and the other will be `float:right;`

You can select the button by their index (i think is what you call it)

```
button:nth(INDEX NUMBER) { /* STYLES */ }
```

for example

```css
span {
  width:100%; //To be safe  
  float:left;
}

span button:nth(1) {
  //#1 for first button, can use button:first-cild() instead
  float:left;
}
span button:nth(2) {
  //#2 for second button
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <button>First Button</button>  
  <button>Second Button</button> 
<span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the buttons are already inside of the item div, put them in a **separate** wrapper div and use CSS to define something like  `padding-top:10px` to keep them along the same height and still leaves you with the ability control how far from the picture it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `.quick-view` and `.button-cart` in the same `<div>` below `.wb-posted_in`.